# Taxonomy list dependent on choice from another taxonomy list, drupal 8

Tags: forms, entity, taxonomy, drupal-8

I have a taxonomy option list **make** where I choose say **Toyota**.

1. I want the second taxonomy option list with the models of Toyota only (Eg. Corolla, hilux etc...).
2. When I choose Benz the second list will then contains C-Class, ML, etc...

I have created the entity vehicle from google examples on xampp localhost, windows 10.

In my vehicle form I'm able to populate the first list. But the second appears empty.

Here is my code. Please help:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $params = NULL) {
  $options = array(); 
  $tax = "make";  
  $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($tax, $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = FALSE);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $options[] = $term->name;
  } 

  $form['make'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Make'),
    'weight' => 0,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => [$this, 'changeOptionsAjax'],
      'wrapper' => 'model_wrapper',
    ),
  );

  $form['model'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Model'),
    'weight' => 1,
    '#options' => $this->getOptions($form_state),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="model_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}

public function getOptions(FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $options = array();
  if ($form_state->getValue('make') == "Benz") { 
    $tax="benz";
  }
  elseif ($form_state->getValue('make') == "BMW") {
    $tax="bmw";
  } 
  elseif ($form_state->getValue('make') == "Toyota") {
    $tax="toyota";
  } 
  else {
    $tax="title";
    // title is just another taxonomy list I'm using as default if make is not found
  }

  $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($tax, $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = FALSE);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $options[] = $term->name;
  }  
  return $options;
}

public function changeOptionsAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['model'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I give you a working sample based on your example `VehiculesForm.php`:

I took the liberty to rename some variable for better readability.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

/**
 * VehiculesForm.
 */
class VehiculesForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * The term Storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorageInterface
   */
  protected $termStorage;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity) {
    $this->termStorage = $entity->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    // Instantiates this form class.
    return new static(
    // Load the service required to construct this class.
    $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'vehicules_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $params = NULL) {
    $brands = $this->termStorage->loadTree('make', 0, NULL, TRUE);
    $options = [];
    if ($brands) {
      foreach ($brands as $brand) {
        $options[$brand->getName()] = $brand->getName();
      }
    }
    $form['brand'] = array(
      '#type'    => 'select',
      '#title'   => $this->t('brand'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#ajax'    => array(
        'callback' => [$this, 'selectModelsAjax'],
        'wrapper'  => 'model_wrapper',
      ),
    );

    $form['model'] = array(
      '#type'      => 'select',
      '#title'     => $this->t('Model'),
      '#options'   => ['_none' => $this->t('- Select a brand before -')],
      '#prefix'    => '<div id="model_wrapper">',
      '#suffix'    => '</div>',
      '#validated' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Send'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * Called via Ajax to populate the Model field according brand.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The form model field structure.
   */
  public function selectModelsAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $options = [];

    $vocabulary = 'title';
    switch ($form_state->getValue('brand')) {
      case 'Benz':
        $vocabulary = 'benz';
        break;
      case 'BMW':
        $vocabulary = 'bmw';
        break;
      case 'Toyota':
        $vocabulary = 'toyota';
        break;
    }

    $models = $this->termStorage->loadTree($vocabulary, 0, NULL, TRUE);
    if ($models) {
      foreach ($models as $model) {
        $options[$model->id()] = $model->getName();
      }
    }
    $form['model']['#options'] = $options;

    return $form['model'];
  }
}
```

---

Also, I suggest you to make some improvments on you code such:

- Don't use a `switch` but link your taxonomies with a reference fields.
- Add validation to ensure security (check we don't spoof your field for example) !!
- Don't use the brandname but the ID. Avoid `$options[$brand->getName()] = $brand->getName();` and use something like `$options[$brand->id()] = $brand->getName();`.

---

Hope it will help you !

Comment: You saved me, now working for me. Had errors at first but added

Comment: You've saved me LOTS, now working Thanks. Had errors at first but added "use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;" and changed "class vehicleForm extends FormBase" to "class VehicleForm extends ContentEntityForm". NB. I also changed "vehicules" back to "vehicles" as my whole entyty files refering to this entity. I'm now working on how to save the entity (vehicle) from the form... as this is not saving entity to database. Thanks Lots

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It will help people seeing the good answer on the page & this also helps contributor to keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: My original form, while I could not implement the taxonomy method, I manually added the respective dropdown lists and could save my vehicle entity to the database. Now while your solution helped me to implement the taxonomy method it won't save the entity and kind of stuck at this....Still learning drupal - also looking for where I mark answer as  "accepted"? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question would help you for the entity creation question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes.
About the validation of questions, here an answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I just can't get this to work in the context I'm working on. I'm using the vehicle example here: [link](http://www.drupal8.ovh/sites/drupal/files/2016-10/vehicle_full_wviews.zip) This example is fully fuctional and saving the vehicle. I simply want to use Kevin Wenger's functionality in vehicleForm of this example. I would have thought my question as a common use case which would have a few examples online but I just can't seem to find it. Can someone please help