# How to create multiple dropdown fields: - based on the value of other dropdown field in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I wanted to create multiple dropdown fields in Drupal 8. These fields will be dependent on the value of previous dropdown field. For instance, if first dropdown field is having value, then second dropdown field will be displayed and ask the user for the input. If user provides the value in second dropdown field, then third field will be visible and so on..

Comment: Does the values inside each "sub"-dropdown will change according the previous dropdown chosen value ? Or it's only about "showing the other dropdown once the previous has been selected" ?

Comment: @KevinWenger, Yes. The value will change based on the previous dropdown chosen value.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look to this answer then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785369/taxonomy-list-dependent-on-choice-from-another-taxonomy-list-drupal-8/45803250#45803250
It's quite the same, some select depends of another select in a Drupal Form